# yum list get last available package

Tags: awk, grep, yum

I need to extract a substring of my latest available package in a repository

```
yum list myCompany-apps-MYPROJECT*
```

Available Packages

```
myCompany-apps-MYPROJECT-0.0.0.41-210409.noarch                      1-160                       myproject
myCompany-apps-MYPROJECT-0.0.0.42-210412.noarch                      1-162                       myproject
myCompany-apps-MYPROJECT-0.0.0.43-210412.noarch                      1-163                       myproject
myCompany-apps-MYPROJECT-0.0.0.44-210412.noarch                      1-173                       myproject
myCompany-apps-MYPROJECT-0.0.0.45-210412.noarch                      1-174                       myproject
myCompany-apps-MYPROJECT-0.0.0.46-210412.noarch                      1-176                       myproject
myCompany-apps-MYPROJECT-0.0.0.47-210412.noarch                      1-179                       myproject
myCompany-apps-MYPROJECT-1.0.0.1-210407.noarch                       1-146                       myproject
myCompany-apps-MYPROJECT-1.0.0.2-210407.noarch                       1-147                       myproject
myCompany-apps-MYPROJECT-1.0.0.3-210408.noarch                       1-149                       myproject
myCompany-apps-MYPROJECT-1.0.0.4-210408.noarch                       1-150                       myproject
```

I want to extract the part after MYPROJECT and before the datetime

I tried :

```
function lastVersion () {
  last_version=$(yum list myCompany-apps-MYPROJECT* | grep "myCompany-apps-MYPROJECT" | awk '{ print $1 }'| awk -F "-" '{ print $4 }' | sort -V | tail -1)
  echo ${last_version}
}
```

The output is : 1.0.0.4 , i need it to be : 0.0.0.47 ( the latest one as indicated in the 2nd column (1-179) , what represents the 2nd column exactly ?)

Thank you very much

Comment: `the latest one as indicated in the 2nd column (1-179)` then sort using second column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all in one `awk` script...

```
... | awk '!/myCompany-apps-MYPROJECT/ {next} 
                                       {sub("-",".",$2)} 
                                max<$2 {max=$2; split($1,f,"-"); maxV=f[4]} 
                                   END {print maxV}' file

0.0.0.47
```

Comment: Thank you ,  this solution is much understandable for me

Answer (score 1):

Extract with regex the data you want and the data you want to sort on. Then sort on the data you want to sort, and leave out the data the you are interested in.

```
yum ... | grep "myCompany-apps-MYPROJECT" |
    sed 's/.*-\([^-]*\)-[^ ]* *[0-9]*-\([0-9]*\).*/\1 \2/' |
    sort -k2n | tail -n1 | cut -d' ' -f1
```

You can learn regex really fast with regexcrosswords ex. https://regexcrossword.com/ .

Comment: @KamiCuk Thank you very much it works perfectly but i must admit i didn't understand the sed part at all . Do you have simpler ? Moreover , is this going to work for future package ( for example 1-1200) ?  Maybe there is a much simpler solution using yum list in order to retrieve the last package by date ?